# How to import dajngo models with their ForeignKeys ond new ids?

Tags: django, import

I need to import some data in django and I stopped on one problem.

I have few models in JSON file and they are all connected via ForeignKey field. In my app I potentialy could have some models with the same ids as those in file, and I would like to keep both. Therefore, for each model in file, while saving it, I would need to generate new id, which as ar as I know is done automatically, if 'id' section in file is empty.

My problem is: what with ForeignKeys? How to keep connection between models, and in the same time for each of them generate new id?